# FIREFOX: plugin or extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon

I developed a function in javascript to change the colors in (all) the images extant on web pages - HTML documents (to help colorblind people in the discrimination of contents).

All the development process was made by programming in javascript (using Dreamweaver environment)
and using some HTML pages (with images) to test. 
The function (of color changing) is because is is associated with the event "onLoad" (in the body tag element) in those HTML test documents.

However, I wanted to put it on the browser, in order that each time an HTML page is loaded, the color of images are changed. More, I want to develop it in order to provide it to anyone.

So, I am looking for the best way of doing and I found that I can made it by creating a Firefox extension (or  plugin?).

Thus, I would like to know:

- The option by Firefox is the best way ?
- In affirmative case, I should develop an extension or a plugin ?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: I decided for the Chrome, because the inicial setup on Firefox scared me.
In Chrome is something accessible.

So, I am developing an Extension for Chrome, which is running already (but it's not rubust enought).
So I am working on it.
Thanks

So, now, I can contribute with my experience to those who wants to beggin :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you're planning on putting it together to work with the browser, really.

There's a useful page below which explains the differences between addons and extensions. I think it pretty much depends on how much you want to add to your project (user interface/menus). If it's literally just to improve the way images are displayed for those with visual impairment, I think it'll probably be an extension.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Extensions

Comment: OP would definitely not use a plugin in this situation, as `Plugins are shared libraries that users can install to display content that the application itself can't display natively`.

Comment: I humbly retract my villainous suggestion that it could be a plugin! Thanks for the correction.